# Spring Integration flow loses subscriber

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-integration, reactor-netty

I have SI flow which consumes `org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketMessage`, does some work with it, which includes handling it's payload using Netty's `ByteBuf`. At some point, an exception occurred in my flow:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler]; nested exception is io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:184) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:175) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.handleError(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:93) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureAccessible(AbstractByteBuf.java:1417) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1356) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.getInt(AbstractByteBuf.java:417) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.hashCode(ByteBufUtil.java:175) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.hashCode(AbstractByteBuf.java:1315) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.24.Final.jar!/:4.1.24.Final]
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.NettyDataBuffer.hashCode(NettyDataBuffer.java:288) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketMessage.hashCode(WebSocketMessage.java:134) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Object.toString(Object.java:236) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
```

After that, handling all binary web socket messages fails with the following exception:

```
2018-11-26T10:38:29,133 ERROR --- [-server-epoll-7] o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler (:) org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'binaryWebSocketMessageChannel'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The [binaryWebSocketMessageChannel] doesn't have subscribers to accept messages, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=MyPayload(payload=org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketMessage@38552d5, session=ReactorNettyWebSocketSession[id=3e0be929, uri=http://localhost:8080/]), headers={id=b09a89ff-f7be-1b43-6f62-40e5c0b5695a, timestamp=1543225109132}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInDeliveryExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:475)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:205)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.onNext(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$1.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:138)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.ReactiveStreamsConsumer$1.hookOnNext(ReactiveStreamsConsumer.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BaseSubscriber.onNext(BaseSubscriber.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetry$RetrySubscriber.onNext(FluxRetry.java:79)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The [binaryWebSocketMessageChannel] doesn't have subscribers to accept messages
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel.doSend(FluxMessageChannel.java:63)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    ... 57 more
```

Could anyone point me in **any** direction to try and solve the problem?
As well, in which cases would SI EIP component (router, transformer, filter, service activator) to unsubscribe from the channel?

For reference, channel type is `org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel`

Edit:

My flow looks like this:

```
WebSocketMessage -> router: (BINARY)  -> binaryWebSocketMessageChannel -> ...
                            (!BINARY) -> nullChannel
```

(I know filter fits better here, I plan to refactor later)

@ArtemBilan the repo with example is here: https://github.com/ioreskovic/Spring-Integration-flow-loses-subscriber

Comment: We need some simple project to play with and reproduce. You provide too little information about configuration. Thanks

Comment: I'll try to extract the parts by the end of this week and host it on GitHub. Thank you :)

Comment: @ArtemBilan I updated the question with repo, steps to reproduce and logs

Comment: You application looks good, but it is not so simple for review: too much custom code. Also prerequisites for replication are too complicated. Can't you just come up with junit test in the project to isolate the problem in a single place? I don't a separate machine to run some other software.

Comment: Sure thing, 1st thing tomorrow. I just posted this example because those where the original steps that led to this bug

Comment: @ArtemBilan I updated the repo with a rudimentary test.

Comment: Have just upgraded your project to Boot 2.1.1 - works well. Testing with 2.0.7...

Comment: Yeah... fails, too. Unfortunately the `onErrorContinue()` is a feature of the Reactor `3.2` and we don't have choice unless upgrade to the latest Spring Boot `2.1.1`.

Comment: Ah, it is what it is :) Thank you once more for helping :D If I ever meet you in person, I'll buy you a beer or any other beverage of your preference :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that `Publisher` in the `FluxMessageChannel` is cancelled in that Spring Integration version.

We started to use `onErrorContinue()` from the Reactor `3.2` in version `5.1`. To fix your problem it would be better to consider to upgrade your application to the latest Spring Boot `2.1.1`.

As we workaround you can consider to swallow an exception in the `BinaryWsmToBytesTransformer` and don't bubble it into the `FluxMessageChannel` back.